# Python: Avoid overwriting dictionary keys in a for loop

Tags: python, api

Python 3.11

I'm not sure if I'm needing to individually create the dictionaries and merge them together? But using the for loop, I'm not able to figure out how to avoid overwriting the first key. I'm wanting to append an additional key:value pair.

```
pokelist = ['rattata', 'meowth', 'eevee']

def get_pokemon_by_type(pokemon_list):
    pokedex = {}
    for pokemon_name in pokemon_list:
        url       = f'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{pokemon_name}'
        response  = requests.get(url)
        weight    = response.json()['weight']
        abilities = []
        for ability in response.json()['abilities']:
            abilities.append(ability['ability']['name'].title())
        for t in response.json()['types']:
            pokedex |= {t['type']['name']: {pokemon_name: {'Abilities': abilities, 'Weight' : weight}}}
    return pokedex
            
get_pokemon_by_type(pokelist)
```

Current output:

```
{'normal': {
'eevee':   {'Abilities': ['Run-Away', 'Adaptability', 'Anticipation'], 'Weight': 65}
}
}
```

Expected output:

```
{'normal': {
'rattata': {'Abilities': ['Run-Away', 'Guts', 'Hustle'],'Weight': 35},
'meowth':  {'Abilities': ['Pickup', 'Technician', 'Unnerve'],'Weight': 42},
'eevee':   {'Abilities': ['Run-Away', 'Adaptability', 'Anticipation'],'Weight': 65}
}
}
```

Comment: How does your current code generate the 'normal' dictionary key?

Comment: @DarkKnight The key is pulled from the API in response.json()['types']['type']['name'].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to *union* the new `dict` with `pokedex`; you want to *map* the name of the current Pokemon to the new `dict`.

```
pokedex.setdefault(t['type']['name'], {})[pokemon_name] = {'Abilities': abilities, 'Weight' : weight}}
```

In your current code, you replace one dict mapped to the name `normal` with a completely new dict that also has the key `normal`, rather than updating the existing `normal` dict.

Comment: StackOverflow edit queue is full, so leaving a comment here. That line should be `pokedex.setdefault(t['type']['name'], {})[pokemon_name] = {'Abilities': abilities, 'Weight' : weight}`.

Comment: Thank you! This did exactly what I was looking for. Now I need to go and learn what setdefault is and what more can be accomplished with it! Thanks again.

Comment: In short, `setdefault(k, v d)` returns `k[v]`, setting `k[v] = d` first *if* `v` is not already in `k`.